# JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: java, maven, exception, junit, apache-phoenix

I have a program that inserts a new patient to HBase in a docker container inside a server. Everything is working fine until I try to change the connection IP to a phoenix query server for running JUnit tests. I am setting the URL in the properties file like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') 
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1105b1f; line: 1, column: 2] 
...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1105b1f; line: 1, column: 2]
```

I am not sure why I'm receiving a `json` parse exception. Because of the external apis, debugging didn't help. I don't even know if the exception is related to the format of the URL in my properties file, to the patient (which comes in xml format) or maybe even to the phoenix client.

I have started the phoenix query server and it looks like it can connect to it, because it was throwing a "connection refused" exception before and now it doesn't.

I added phoenix in my pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-server</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0-HBase-1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but I don't know if I have to add something else for the phoenix-thin-client. If I have to, I couldn't find that dependency, so I just assumed it's included.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

This is the exception the server throws:

```
> > 2016-05-05 08:52:11,979 WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel: / java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException:
> While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the
> middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been
> truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AbstractHandler.apply(AbstractHandler.java:98)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufHandler.apply(ProtobufHandler.java:38)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.server.AvaticaProtobufHandler.handle(AvaticaProtobufHandler.java:68)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:245)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException:
> While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the
> middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been
> truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.truncatedMessage(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:70)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipRawBytesSlowPath(CodedInputStream.java:1293)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipRawBytes(CodedInputStream.java:1276)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:197)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipMessage(CodedInputStream.java:273)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:200)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.proto.Common$WireMessage.<init>(Common.java:11627)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.proto.Common$WireMessage.<init>(Common.java:11595)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.proto.Common$WireMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(Common.java:12061)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.proto.Common$WireMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(Common.java:12055)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:137)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:168)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:185)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.proto.Common$WireMessage.parseFrom(Common.java:11760)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufTranslationImpl.parseRequest(ProtobufTranslationImpl.java:236)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufHandler.decode(ProtobufHandler.java:42)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufHandler.decode(ProtobufHandler.java:28)
>         at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AbstractHandler.apply(AbstractHandler.java:95)
>         ... 11 more
```

Comment: You're probably getting html back. I don't see why debugging couldn't help... But you state you expect xml back-which isn't json.

Comment: If debugging didn't work, you could try capturing the server response using a network sniffer.

Comment: In my case it was due to the server down and throwing 404 Not Found. Please check your response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you upgrade your Phoenix server properly? It looks like it trying to use both the JSON and Protocol Buffer protocols to connect. It should be one or the other.

Comment: I didn't change the serialization at all. I guess that's the problem then. Doing some debugging, I see that it's setting json as the phoenix.queryserver.serialization by default, but I don't know how to change that. Is it doing something like this in the connection? properties.setProperty("phoenix.queryserver.serialization", "PROTOBUF");

Comment: try adding `serialization=PROTOBUF` in your jdbc connection string. Though I thought that would have been the default for both the server and client if both are version 4.7

Comment: This worked. Apparently JSON was the default (or "someone else" is changing it somewhere and I'm not aware of it!). Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are providing authorization, headers and other parameters correctly.

I **solved** by checking these steps.